# Fujifilm X100F tethering?

Tags: fujifilm, tethering, fujifilm-x100

Has anyone managed to tether a Fujifilm x100F to a Mac?  I can't find anything online. I'm assuming it's not possible.

Things I've explored:

- Tethered Capture Plug-in for Adobe Photoshop Lightroom: The Adobe Lightroom plug-in isn't advertised to work with the X100F. I'm assuming this is correct.
- FUJIFILM X Acquire: With the X100F, the X Acquire software only allows the camera's settings to be saved and restored. Tethering isn't an option as it is with some other "X" cameras (the XPro2, XT2, and, presumably, now the XT3). I've installed the X Acquire software and confirmed this to be the case. I've also written to FUJIFILM suggesting they include tethering for the X100F in any future upgrades, for what it's worth.
- A Toshiba Flashair SD card: I've been advised this may be a possibility, but I'd need to write a shell script to download the files from the card to the computer as they are taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CaptureOne is another program that supports tethering and live view of just about every camera that supports that functionality. According to their [Fuji camera support page](https://www.captureone.com/en/resources/tech-specs/camera-support-fujifilm), it doesn't appear the X100F supports tethering or remote live view:

> | Model | Version Added | Required Run Modes | File Support | Tethered/Live View | Notes |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Fujifilm X100F | 10.0.2 | Express Fujifilm/Fujifilm/Pro | RAF | No/No | Xtrans to DNG not supported |

Based on CaptureOne's inability to support it, my guess is that the X100F inherently doesn't support tethering or tethered live view, at least for any 3rd party solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but I haven't done it myself.  One way to do it is to download Fuji's free tethering software FujiFilm X Acquire.  Download link and instructions are here:

https://fujifilm-x.com/global/stories/fujifilm-x-acquire-features-users-guide/

Comment: Unfortunately, with the X100F, the X Acquire software only allows the camera's settings to be saved and restored. Tethering isn't an option as it is with some other "X" cameras (the XPro2, XT2, and, presumably, now the XT3); unless, there is some workaround ... ?